# How to use ContentProvider with online database

Tags: java, android, database, android-contentprovider

From my understanding, extends `ContentProvider` facilitate the interaction with local database stored in device. But I'm not sure if how to implement `ContentProvider` with an online database. Does `ContentProvider` only works with local database? I'm thinking of using both with cache, but I'm very inexperienced with regard to this aspect. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you expose that online database?

Comment: @Luksprog: I use URL to a php file which returns data as JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

The [Contentprovider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) interface design actually abstracts the actual persistence details away from your data access, in theory making any kind of data source possible. In practice, the performance of a contentprovider accessing it's data over the network will be poor at best due to the overhead compared to a local datasource such as SQLite / files.

Preloading/cacheing is probably a good idea!